# Why discriminant method gives wrong answer when searching parabola that touches x axis?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Define a so that parabola y = a*x^2 - 5*a*x + 5*a+5 touches x axis.

Touching x axis means that discriminant is 0 (parabola has one double zero on x axis - that is a touch).

Or it can also mean that the vertex is on x axis, which means vertex's coordinates are (x,0).

Now if I calculate a by first clue, discriminant equal to 0, I get:

D=0 a=a b=-5a c=5*a+5

D=b^2 - 4 * a * c

0 = b^2 - 4 * a *c

0=25a^2-20a^2+20a

0=5a^2+20a

-5a^2=20a

a=-4

This gives us parabola y=-4x^2 + 20x -15. This parabola in wolfram alpha for some reason doesn't touch x axis, but passes it by very little.

Now if we calculate a by second clue, that is the vertex, we get:

y coordinate of vertex is calculated with the next formula:

y= -(b^2 - 4*a*c)/4*a

y coordinate is 0 so:

0 = -(5a^2 + 20a)/4a

...

a=4

This gives us parabola y= 4x^2 -20x + 25 which is in wolfram alpha a correct graph that touches axis x.

My question is, why does discriminant method give wrong answer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "thouching the $\;x$-axis" you seem to mean that the parabola is tangent to the $\;x$-axis, right? This is, that it has one unique (double) real root$\;\iff \;$ its discriminant is zero. "Touching" can be misleading here.

Comment: And try to write mathematics using LaTeX ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parabola seems to be $\;y=ax^2-5ax+5a+5\;$ , and we **must** assume $\;a\neq 0\;$ otherwise this is *not* a quadratic, so

$$\Delta=(5a)^2-4a(5a+5)=5a^2-20a=5a(a-4)=0\iff a=\begin{cases}0\;\;\color{red}X\\4\;\;\color{red}\checkmark\end{cases}$$

(Can you see your mistake in the discriminant?)

The vertex coordinates of a parabola $\;y=ax^2+bx+c\;$ are given by

$$V=\left(-\frac b{2a}\;,\;-\frac\Delta{4a}\right)$$

so in our case we get that the vertex is (remember: $\;a\neq 0\;$ ) :

$$V=\left(\frac{5a}{2a}\;,\;-\frac{5a(a-4)}{4a}\right)=\left(\frac52\;,\;-\frac54(a-4)\right)$$

and the above point is on the $\;x$-axis iff $\;a=4\;$ ...same result!

Answer (score 1):

Just a sign error. The discriminant is $25a^2-4a(5a+5)$, which is $5a^2-20a$.